# Where are C11 optional feature macros?

Tags: c

In the C11 standard is written that compilers should provide some macros to test for optional feature presence. In what headers do I find them?

For example where is located `__STDC_NO_VLA__`?

With GCC, i.e., if I try to find `__STDC_NO_COMPLEX__` into `complex.h` I don't find it there...

Comment: The test is not for the macro's value, but for whether it's defined or not. And they are pre-defined by the preprocessor if at all. So no need to include anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are not defined in any header, a compiler will define them itself.

You can dump all of the preprocessor defines. For example for gcc write:

```
gcc -dM -E - < /dev/null
```

For example for me:

```
bob@bob-fedora:~/trunk/software$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 20121109 (Red Hat 4.7.2-8)
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

bob@bob-fedora:~/trunk/software$ gcc -std=gnu11 -dM -E - < /dev/null | grep STDC
#define __STDC_HOSTED__ 1
#define __STDC_UTF_16__ 1
#define __STDC_VERSION__ 201112L
#define __GNUC_STDC_INLINE__ 1
#define __STDC_UTF_32__ 1
#define __STDC__ 1
```

In the example you gave, `__STDC_NO_VLA__` the presence of this means that the compiler does not supported variable length arrays. You could write:

```
#ifdef __STDC_NO_VLA__
#error Your compiler does not support VLAs! Please use a supported compiler.
#endif
```

Or

```
#ifndef __STDC_NO_VLA__
// code using variable length arrays
#else
// fallback code for when they are not supported
#endif
```

Comment: and how can I test it in my code, with #ifdef directive?

Comment: You can test with `#ifdef`, I have added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

if **STDC_NO_COMPLEX** is defined, it indicates that there is is no complex.h

**STDC_NO_COMPLEX** is defined by the compiler, not by header file

source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex

Comment: Ironically, the C11 standard Annex B says that STDC_NO_COMPLEX should be located in complex.h, which doesn't make any sense. Seems to be an error in the (non-normative) Annex B.