# Define a matrix in C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I started to learn `C` and started a new argument: `the matrices`.
I saw that you can define a matrix in two different ways

**WAY 1**

The first way using the subscript operator`[]`

```
const int N = 3, M = 4;
int matrix[N][M];
```

but as this it is difficlt to pass the arguments in the functions becouse the 
the compiler has to know the matrix number of columns when it compiles the program. so you have to do a function that works only for matrices with `n` columns

```
int my_func( int matrix[][3], const int num_lines){...}
```

**WAY 2**

The second way: use an array of arrays

```
const int N = 3, M = 4;
int** m = (int**) calloc(N, sizeof(int*))
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    m[i] = (int*) calloc(M, sizeof(int))
}
```

So doing so you can easily pass the matrix pointer to a function an work fluently with it but the only problem is the efficency in the memory allocation and the 
the recall of values.

**WAY 3?**

Actually i thought that there can be a third way and i was wondering if it was correct doing this

```
const int N = 3, M = 4;
int array[N*M];
for (int i=0; i<N; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j<M; j++){
        printf("%d%d: %d\n", i, j, array[ i * M + j ]);
    }
}
```

Doing so by my point of view should be as efficency as the first way that i wrote but u can work with it more fluently in the functions becouse you need only to pass the lines and the columns as arguments

```
int my_func( const int* matrix, const int num_lines, const int num_columns){...}
```

Is the `way 3` right?

Comment: Yes; in fact, the rows and columns could be part of a `struct` with the array, then you'd only have to pass one value.

Comment: So am i correct by sayng that the third way is the 'best' one? @Neil

Comment: It depends on what you are using it for. Of the three, it is the most abstract.

Comment: Way 1 and 3, as you have coded them, are only guaranteed defined in `C99`, `C89` you could only use [integer constants](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/integer_constant) and `C11` made variable-sized arrays an [optional feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22914206/where-are-c11-optional-feature-macros/22914369).

Comment: _Viz_, if one replaced `const int` with `#define` then they would work on all versions of `C`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the `way 3` right?

From the memory management system, the `way 3` is *cheaper* as you don't have too many allocations as in `way 2`. But it is also limiting you in terms of maximum matrix size, which can be placed on the stack.

If you take the best from `way 2` and `way 3`, you will end up with something like

```
typedef struct  {
    unsigned M;
    unsigned N;
    int *data;
} Matrix;

Matrix create_matrix(unsigned M, unsigned N) {
    Matrix matrix;
    matrix.M = M;
    matrix.N = N;
    matrix.data = (int*) calloc(M * N, sizeof(int));
    return matrix;
}

int* get_matrix_element(Matrix *matrix, unsigned m, unsigned n) {
    return matrix->data + m * matrix->N + n;
}

void delete_matrix(Matrix *matrix) {
    free(matrix->data);
}
```

Comment: Note that an array does not have to be on the stack; it can be global or static. You can also assign the result of malloc to a pointer to array and then use it like a 2-dimensional array: `int (*arr)[3] = malloc(12*sizeof(int)); arr[3][2] = 1;` for a 4x3 matrix.

Comment: Essentialy (that's a link for a fork, original library harder to link directly) https://github.com/yageek/Meschach/blob/master/matrix.h. Meshach got an extended structure because they support some kind of sparse matrices, I think.

Comment: You can save a redirect if you store the array after the dimensions, but that's probably more work.